# Creating variable by group (R)

Tags: r, dplyr

My data looks something like this:

```
      CPUBID MPUBID  CSEX  CMOB  CYRB  twin  twinfam
       <int>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>    <int>
   1     201      2     2     3  1993     0        0
   2     202      2     2    11  1994     0        0
   3     301      3     2    10  1983     1        1
   4     302      3     2    10  1983     1        1
   5     303      3     2     4  1986     0        1
   6     401      4     1     8  1980     0        0
   7     403      4     2     3  1997     0        0
   8     801      8     2     3  1976     0        0 
   9     802      8     1     5  1979     0        0
   10    803      8     2     9  1982     0        0
```

`dput()` version:

```
structure(list(CPUBID = c(201L, 202L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 401L, 
403L, 801L, 802L, 803L), MPUBID = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
8L, 8L, 8L), CSEX = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), 
    CMOB = c(3L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 9L), CYRB = c(1993L, 
    1994L, 1983L, 1983L, 1986L, 1980L, 1997L, 1976L, 1979L, 1982L
    ), twin = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), twinfam = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("CPUBID", 
"MPUBID", "CSEX", "CMOB", "CYRB", "twin", "twinfam"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

CPUBID is individual ID, MPUBID is mother's ID, CSEX = sex, CMOB = month of birth etc. Twin is a binary variable indicating that the individual is a twin. "twinfam" is the variable I'm trying to create. i.e. if any member of the household is a twin, this binary indicator takes value == 1 for all members of that household.

I tried using:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(MPUBID) %>% 
    mutate(twinfam = as.numeric(count(twin == 1) > 0))
```

but this gives me the error:

```
 Error: no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "logical"
```

Any suggestions for a way to fix this, or perhaps a better route to creating the desired variable? Thanks.

Comment: So for every `twin` variable as 1, you want to have a vector having that `MPUBID` as 1?

Comment: use `sum` instead of `count`. The error is coming from the `count` in the `mutate` call since `dplyr::count` only works on data frames and you gave it a logical vector. This is one of the key problems with piping as narrowing down the error can be tricky in longer pipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'MPUBID', we check whether there are `any` value in 'twin' that is not a 0 and convert that logical vector to binary (`as.integer`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, twinfam1 := as.integer(any(twin!=0)) , by = MPUBID]
```

---

Or using `dplyr` with the same logic.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(MPUBID) %>%
  mutate(twinfam = as.integer(any(twin!=0)))
#  CPUBID MPUBID  CSEX  CMOB  CYRB  twin twinfam
#    <int>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>   <int>
#1     201      2     2     3  1993     0       0
#2     202      2     2    11  1994     0       0
#3     301      3     2    10  1983     1       1
#4     302      3     2    10  1983     1       1
#5     303      3     2     4  1986     0       1
#6     401      4     1     8  1980     0       0
#7     403      4     2     3  1997     0       0
#8     801      8     2     3  1976     0       0
#9     802      8     1     5  1979     0       0
#10    803      8     2     9  1982     0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `base R`

```
selected <- unique(df$MPUBID[with(df,twin==1)])
df$twinfam <- ifelse(df$MPUBID %in% selected,1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

One - liner in base

```
as.numeric(df$MPUBID %in% df$MPUBID[df$twin == 1])

#[1] 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
```